# Standard ActionBar icon without default left-margin / padding

Tags: android, android-actionbar, margin

With **Holo theme** for API level > 14 I retrieve the well kown look with a left margin for the icon in the `ActionBar` as follows:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
```

[image]

When applying **Material-theme** with **AppCompat_v7** support (not changing the code or using the preferred new `ToolBar` instead) the left margin is missing.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```

[image]

Why and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

As a first workaround I added a **Layer List** drawable resource named **icon.xml** to *res/drawable/* like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:left="20dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

and referenced this drawable as logo instead of the original icon itself in the **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
        <activity
            android:logo="@drawable/icon" ...
```